# Does btc-e require verification for coin to USD conversion

Tags: exchanges, litecoin, btce, altcoin

I know that btc-e requires verification to withdrawal USD, 
but do they require verification to convert to USD and let sit until I want to trade it for other coins?

Again.. NO usd withrawal. only BTC->USD -- USD->BTC/LTC/etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use them for my primary exchange. You can sell BTC/LTC/etc. for USD and hold the USD in your account without verification. As far as I can tell, there is no verification process nor a way to withdraw USD other than as a BTC-E credit. In my experience, you're better off finding a *reliable* third party that specializes in buying BTC when you are ready to cash out.

Comment: Indeed, from past experience, BTC-e will ask you to get verified only if their bank asks so (which may happen if you are depositing/withdrawing a lot). Until then, you can trade as much as you want without being verified.

Comment: Confirmed.
I've been trading USD->BTC->USD with no issues for the past few days. It *seems* like their bank will only ask for verification if you are withdrawing USD.

Comment: It makes sense really. All your USD is, until you try to withdraw it, is a number in a database. They have X reserve USD in their bank account and will transfer some of it to your bank account when you request, but until then, it's really just sitting in their bank account. No need to verify you to add and subtract from a variable in a database. That only becomes necessary when they need to send it to your bank.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the BTC-e help desk.

For information their exchange is incredibly unresponsive to help requests, and if you are a new customer or if you transfer any money in to the exchange you have to jump through hoops to withdraw.... or wait the customary 30+ days until your account becomes responsive again.